# Rails element if first time appearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Post with :mark, :text

I have a list with my post

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
  # todo
  <% if p.mark? %>
    <%= p.mark %> <%= sweet_thing(p.text) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= sweet_thing(p.text) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I need to show p.mark name instead #todo where p.mark first time appearance.
Final txt example:

Audi

Audi, text-text-text-text.

Audi, text-text-text-text.

Audi, text-text-text-text.

Ford

Ford, text-text-text-text.

Ford, text-text-text-text.

Ford, text-text-text-text.

Ford, text-text-text-text.

UPDATE

My txt render in controller

```
 def txt_receiver
    @posts = Post.where("created_at >= ?", 7.days.ago.utc).find(:all, order: "mark, LOWER(post)")
    render "txt_for_newspapper", formats: ["text"]
  end
```

Comment: What if elements are out of order? Audis and Fords mixed together?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i need order (add for you my controller method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious solution is to keep track of seen marks.

```
<% seen_marks = {} %>
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
  <% unless seen_marks[p.mark] %>
    <%= p.mark %>
    <% seen_marks[p.mark] = true %>
  <% end %>

  # rest of your code

<% end %>
```

A better solution (I think) involves grouping posts by their mark and then outputting in groups. But I'm not sure whether it will match your logic regarding missing marks.

```
<% @posts.group_by(&:mark).each do |mark, posts| %>
  <%= mark %>

  <% posts.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.mark if mark %> <%= sweet_thing(p.text) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: txt_for_newspapper.text.erb:6: both block arg and actual block given

Comment: @Savroff: yeah, forgot `.each` there